# Problems with parfor-loop in command line execution

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am trying to execute this piece of code:

```
parpool('local',4);

range = 1000;

parfor i = 1:range
    A_test(i) = sqrt(i);
end
```

It runs perfectly in the MATLAB-Desktop window, but when I try to run it from the command line using

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run script.m"
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using onCleanup (line 50)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in parfor_test (line 9)
parfor i = 1:range

Error in run (line 96)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

I read, that I might have to preallocate the vector A_test, so I modified the code like this:

```
parpool('local',4);

range = 1000;

A_test = zeros(1,range);

parfor i = 1:range
    A_test(i) = sqrt(i);
end
```

Now I don't get any errors, but A_test does not get filled with sqrt-numbers, but stays filled with zeros.
Do you have any ideas, what I could do to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `run` in your command. Just do:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "script"
```

**edit** Just realised that I had a typo in the above command (no need for .m extension -> that will cause an error)

Comment: That doesn't work. I get the error "Unexpected MATLAB operator".

Comment: works for me... What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: MATLAB R2015a - academic use

Comment: I don't have R2015a to test it on - but I cant imagine that's the issue...  What does it say if you type `lasterror` at the command window?